# What is the difference between variance and V.a.R?

Tags: variance, econometrics, finance

I'm currently reading All The Devils Are Here - a historical account of the economic conditions leading up to the 2007/08 financial crash.

The authors have just introduced a new invention for measuring risk - the Value at Risk (or VaR) - and what's not clear to me is the relevance of this to what we commonly call variance (in relevance to a Gaussian).

How does VaR extend this concept and differ from the most basic statistical analysis?

Comment: it has nothing to do with variance

Comment: It would help to read a description of what VAR is.  Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_at_risk.  I was interested to discover, upon searching that article for "variance," that there is something called "variance-covariance VAR."  You can even find a thread about that on the [quant site](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/42417/variance-covariance-var-how-to-get-the-volatility).  Thus, although the *concept* of VAR is unrelated to variance, connections do exist (cc @carlo).

Comment: @whuber, mind the capitalization: VaR ~ value at risk, while VAR ~ vector autoregression.

Comment: @Richard Thank you.  I doubt anyone would misunderstand these acronyms within the present context, but in other contexts one would want to be careful.

Comment: @whuber, of course.

Comment: It wouldn't been the first time I've seen a value at risk/vector autoregression confusion crop up.

Comment: @carlo - but given the assumption of a normal distribution is the VaR not just a coordinate transform of the variance?